# Operating System

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system

On a system with 2^24 bytes of memory and fixed partitions, all of size 65,536
bytes, what is the minimum number of bits needed in an entry in the process table
to record the partition to which a process has been allocated?

Thanks

Comment: How many partitions are there?  Do you have 224 bytes of system memory and 224 partitions?  I suspect there's an error or typo in this question.

Comment: @cdhowie 2^24 bytes of memory
Typing mistake

Answer (score 2):

This is simple math.

There are 2<sup>24</sup> / 65536 = **256** partitions.

ceil(log2(**256**)) = **8** bits to encode a specific partition number.